# Merge Tag [fire-emblem-the-sacred-stones] to [fire-emblem-sacred-stones]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-merging

Merge the tag [fire-emblem-the-sacred-stones](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-the-sacred-stones) to [fire-emblem-sacred-stones](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-sacred-stones) because both are about the same game **[Fire Emblem : The Sacred Stones](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/Fire_Emblem:_The_Sacred_Stones)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It looks like Wrigglenite went ahead and re-tagged the two questions to [fire-emblem-the-sacred-stones](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-the-sacred-stones).

Note that our general preference is to use the full, official title for the tag name whenever possible, only deviating from this for games with long names, or for SEO purposes (e.g. the PlayStation tags: [ps1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps1) etc)

Comment: Cool. Thank you!